# VSTO 2005 Add-in fails to start if .NET framework 4 is installed

Tags: .net, vsto, ms-office

I have a VSTO 2005 Office add-in for Office 2003, built against .NET 2, that runs just fine, but it only works if the .NET Framework 4 is *not* installed.

If I install the .NET Framework 4, then it won't start. I've enabled debugging by setting the environment variable `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` to `0`, so I can see the error during startup of Office applications:

The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.DomainFactory' threw an exception.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.DomainFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 or later is not correctly installed. Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the Microsoft Office System requires the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 or later."
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.PolicyInfo.InitializeFromConfigurationFiles(PolicyLevel& enterprisePolicy, PolicyLevel& machinePolicy, PolicyLevel& userPolicy)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.PolicyInfo..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.DomainFactory..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated, as I don't know where to go with this.

Comment: You need to gather some more info. Have a look at the troubleshooting tips here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brijs/archive/2008/10/10/tips-tricks-for-troubleshooting-for-office-add-ins-part-1.aspx

Comment: I just tried AddInSpy, which only told that my add-in was installed OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to a conflict with another Office add-in that had been built using [Add-In Express](http://www.add-in-express.com). If that other add-in was uninstalled, my add-in worked OK. Updating the version of the Add-in Express assemblies the other add-in was using also solved this issue.